# Polynomial Regression :ValueError: shapes (88,1) and (3,1) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 3 (dim 0)

Tags: python, pandas, polynomials

This is my data:

```
Sale Price  Year Sold
48  395000.0    2015
1   260000.0    2015
50  425000.0    2016
30  2142000.0   2016
29  377011.0    2016
... ... ...
47  740000.0    2020
50  448208.0    2020
51  975000.0    2020
27  265000.0    2020
1   450000.0    2020
```

I am trying to fit a polynomial regression line but I get the error:ValueError: shapes (88,1) and (3,1) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 3 (dim 0), and I am not sure how to resolve it.

```
train_x = np.asanyarray(x_train).reshape(-1,1)
train_y = np.asanyarray(y_train).reshape(-1,1)

poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree = 2) 
X_poly = poly.fit_transform(train_x) 

poly.fit(X_poly, train_y) 
lin2 = LinearRegression() 
lin2.fit(X_poly, train_y) 

plt.scatter(x, y, color = 'blue') 

plt.plot(train_x, lin2.predict(train_x), color = 'red') 


plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use reshape method only if your input is a vector. Can you share your full code in git repo.

```
train_x = np.asanyarray(x_train).reshape(-1,1)
train_y = np.asanyarray(y_train).reshape(-1,1)
```

Assume you reshape x_train, it will convert shape (10,2) to shape (20,1) and for y_train shape will be (10,1). You can clearly see in this case you will get error.